# Rails 3 + Mobile + Fileuploading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mobile, file-upload, mime-types

I'm trying to set up a fileuploader from a mobile version of my webpage.
I did this
 `Mime::Type.register_alias "text/html", :mobile`

in my mimetypes file, but "file_field" doesn't send the data when the format is mobile. I already tested It.

Any suggestions about what am I missing here? something about the format? the way rails manage file uploading?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well... this problem was associated with other issue. The problem was that mobile requests are being executed via AJAX and I'm sending a File here. So, files cannot be sent via AJAX in a native way. I had to use a library for that (Jquery Forms).

Hope this help other people.
Cheers,